# Minko error building SDK

Tags: c++, windows, html, emscripten, minko

I am trying to compile the Minko framework on Windows 10 targeted at HTML.  However, I'm hitting an error running the build_html5.bat script.

I've followed the instructions and completed all the steps (except for moving from the main branch to the dev branch, which is listed as optional).  I cloned the source, set the new Environment Variable, ran the install_emscripten.bat file, and ran the specified commands in the emscripten command prompt.

However, when I try to run the build_html5.bat script, I get the following error:

[image]

I've looked in the MINKO_HOME directory and was able to find the jsoncpp.cpp file, but the jsoncpp.o file is not where in the directory specified in the command being called.  The only file in MINKO_HOME/framework/obj/html5/release is a file named 'linker.rsp'.

I tried pulling down the dev branch into a different directory and updating the MINKO_HOME variable accordingly.  I couldn't find the tool directory, but I was able to run the script scripts/solution_gmake_full.bat, after my first error trying to run build_html5_full.bat.  When trying to run build_html5_full.bat, however, I get a different error:

[image]

Am I missing something here?  Any help would be appreciated!

Sincerely,

Alex

Comment: Can you try the dev branch to see if it works any better?

Comment: @Jean-MarcLeRoux: I've updated the question with my attempt to work from the dev branch.  Please see the second error above.  Thank you!